# Sharepoint list items not getting updated

Tags: list, sharepoint, export, updates, new-operator

Recently data edited in sharepoint list not getting updated and not showed in exported file also.Issue was started to appear from last week.same list is connected to a power app also
Any solution on this

tried to modify permissions. Still no effects

Comment: Does this problem occur with all lists?